# How to prepend line number for C++ code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there no line numbers in the code listings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings)

I want to display C++ code prepended with line numbers on Stack Overflow. The indented C++ code is formatted with Stack Overflow's built-in `<!-- language: cpp -->` tag.

I need this because gdb (gcc debugger on Linux) outputs the error for a certain line number in a C++ source file and the C++ code is quite long.

So I was just wondering, is it possible to display line numbers for C++ code posted and formatted on Stack Overflow?

Comment: If this were implemented, it would have to include a capability to copy the code *without the line numbers.* Otherwise, it's a non-starter.

Comment: You are right. The coders who will read the post shouldn't have any difficulties reading the posting too. I agree with the policy made by stackoverflow. So the coding should be as minimum as one could. I saw this line numbering on other websites and copying is very cumbersome. At first I was wanting this feature for temporary convenience. But stackoverflow is right about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extremely sorry I didn't search properly before posting.

I found the answer here:

[Why are there no line numbers in the code listings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings?rq=1)

[Line numbers in code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/line-numbers-in-code?rq=1)

So it is better not to have line numbers. I agree 100% with stackoverflow's policy.

Thanks stackoverflow.com for doing a superb job.