# Can we pretty please have a full screen mode for large code blocks?

Tags: feature-request, design, code-formatting, code-block

This would be soo easy to implement with just a little bit of jquery...  And, it would make reading large code blocks sooo much easier.  Pretty please?   I'll even write it...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44094/greasemonkey-script-to-expand-scrolling-code-blocks

Comment: Make a user script.

Comment: Related: [Reduce the empty space on each side of pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100940)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not talking with authority so don't quote me on that but posting overly large source files on Stack Overflow is generally [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings).

People should only post short snippets or the most relevant parts of their code. So in essence one should avoid large code blocks.

Comment: I agree, if someone is posting so much code that the area currently set aside to show a block of code becomes cumbersome, then it is *too much* code. The solution is not to change the display area, but to encourage the poster to reduce the amount of code.

Comment: +1, @octaviandamiean, @lassevkarlsen, I think this is a valid point.  However, there certainly must be exceptional circumstances where long code blocks are justified?  Wouldn't it be better to have a warning appear prior to maximizing the full screen mode than to not have the feature at all?  Or, it could be a restricted privilege for users whose reputation has proven they will use it judiciously.

Comment: Sometimes it's not the number of lines of code (say 10-20 long), but rather the width.  I often find myself sketching out an answer in my IDE, then when it comes time to post I'm doing formatting gymnastics to make it fit left to right.

Comment: But what about for code review?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to allow more of my screen to be used for code blocks.

I imagine [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) users would like it too:
[Searching for substrings (NSString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525601/searching-for-substrings-nsstring)
[How to make a custom tableView cell accessory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525296/how-to-make-a-custom-tableview-cell-accessory)
[Populating TableView cells using GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524036/populating-tableview-cells-using-gcd)
[sharing multiples items with sharekit on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523592/sharing-multiples-items-with-sharekit-on-facebook) 
[Expected specifier-qualifier-list before error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522065/expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-error)
[Custom tableViewCell resignFirstResponder when scrolled offscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521528/custom-tableviewcell-resignfirstresponder-when-scrolled-offscreen)
[Core Data: object in a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520307/core-data-object-in-a-predicate)
[Finding generic Bluetooth devices within reach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520185/finding-generic-bluetooth-devices-within-reach)
[IOS: tableview delegate methods for two tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519673/ios-tableview-delegate-methods-for-two-tableview)
[What happens if a file already exists and you try writing to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518754/what-happens-if-a-file-already-exists-and-you-try-writing-to-it)
[Cannot set UILabel properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518640/cannot-set-uilabel-properties)
[How to copy TableView cell data to a NSMutable Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516298/how-to-copy-tableview-cell-data-to-a-nsmutable-array)
[how to retain values in the following method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515618/how-to-retain-values-in-the-following-method)