# Can we have a button that makes the answer box full screen?

Tags: feature-request

I am typing this question in a box that has formatting options above and a little drag down thing on the bottom, that lets me expand the box if my question (or answer!) is long.

However, on some sites like Codegolf, questions can get very lengthy as they have to be specific about things like rules and giving example test cases. I myself have written a Codegolf challenge in the past and I noted that it was really annoying to have to drag the bar down a bunch of times so that I could easily see my whole response without having to scroll.

Can we have a 'fullscreen' button?

If you browse reddit and have RES installed you will see that when typing a comment or a post there will be a button for 'Big editor'; this is exactly what I am talking about. It also has a 'live preview' on the side, while here its below. It would be nice I guess if the preview was on the side.

This is not related to questions such as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81633/can-we-pretty-please-have-a-full-screen-mode-for-large-code-blocks) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36726/where-is-the-show-me-the-code-in-full-screen-show-me-the-code-in-full-screen) where they are discussing horizontal scrolling in already posted answers; I'm talking about the process of answering a question.

Comment: This would just be fiddly, and for no real benefit - the text flows down on Stack, not across, so the current option to drag-down the answer box is perfectly fine if you want to write loads.

Comment: The community answer to this appears to be "hell no". I disagree but we are in the minority. Have you seen this: http://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure it is a viable request - the answer box as it appears currently with its preview shows perfectly how the answer would look, because SE doesn't stretch answer to the full window width.

Also, mostly on SO, I prefer seing the whole page, with real time comments and answers coming or any changes to the question - full screen mode would prevent it. I would never use this option. This reminds me about the usual editor vs. inline one - I use the latter in any case, mostly because of mentioned reasons.

Comment: Your first point is valid, but about the second point: the full screen idea is a temporary one only for answering or editing a post. Nothing about viewing answers or questions would appear, the only changes come when you decide to write or edit soething.

Comment: @Faraz That's exactly what I've said.