# Formatting Sandbox's page is wider than necessary

Tags: bug, design, ipad, sandbox

No, I'm not talking about making the [question/answer box full screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259033/can-we-have-a-button-that-makes-the-answer-box-full-screen).

I'm saying that the page itself will not fit my iPad screen for the mobile-web (Safari) version. Here is the incident here:

[image]

No, I can't shrink the page because my hand is too small to go across the entire iPad and take a screenshot correctly. Usually, any other pages I go to will fit the screen, all but this one. So why is the page not as wide as the entire screen like this one?:

[image]

Comment: It's because of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257138/260841)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ go ahead, post an answer ;)

Comment: Most amount of comments in 45 seconds...

Comment: This is not mobile web, you are viewing the full site theme which is NOT meant for mobile devices. It might work, but it won't look pretty. You can click the link called "mobile" in the footer and you will get the mobile friendly version, most likely with full width contents.

Comment: So Apple supports the full theme??!! That's a shocker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only happens on the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122).

It's because of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257138/260841):

[image]

Removing the <kbd>kbd</kbd> element via Developer Tools fixes the page - go blame [Cool Guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/293416/cool-guy).

It's kind of expected... it's a *Formatting* Sandbox!

Comment: Yuh, this sandbox is a pro window screwer.