# Add line numbers to code sections?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there no line numbers in the code listings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings)

Please add line numbers to code sections.  It will help when discussing the code.

Comment: That's actually handled here (by Meta Stack Overflow), so ask away! Note that if your request gets downvoted, though, it isn't necessarily bad *per se*: downvotes often indicate that the community doesn't think the proposal would be a good idea. Likewise, upvotes on feature proposals often indicate agreement.

Comment: @Chris so all i need to do is to ask another question and suggest a feature.

Comment: Actually, it would probably just be easier for you to edit this question.

Comment: Use the _feature-request_ tag when you request a feature. But wait, you did already! This is really confusing me...

Comment: I would rather feed my firstborn to packs of wild gerbils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great to have this as an **OPTION**, for those cases where it could come in handy.