# How I can downvote the acceptation

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Well, I want to downvote the acceptation of an answer. How I can do that?

ps. I don't want to downvote the answer, I want to downvote the acceptation. For example in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119) I think that the question owner should not mark this answer as accepted. I want to downvote the acceptation.

EDIT: Thanks to the owner of the question for kindly marking-back his question as unaccepted.

Comment: There's no such concept. What are you trying to achieve anyway? Why not add a comment?

Comment: You better submit a better new answer explaining what is missing/wrong from the original OR upvote a correct answer, leaving a comment on the correct one explaining why it is correct and/or leave a comment on the accepted answer explaining why that can't be correct

Comment: voting system concept is for your acceptation and add comment why it is wrong

Comment: The problem is; if I will ask the same feature now within a question, my question will be marked as duplicate because of this question/answer. But I think it is a necessary feature. So that's why I want to downvote the acceptance.

Comment: I don't think it is related, because the answer owner gave his own response to the question. There is no problem with the answer.

Comment: And what is wrong with a new question asked by you that goes like "In this question is shown that blah blah BUT that answer doesn't work for me because *describe exact, with code/ verfiyable examples, off-site prove and clear explanation what is different in your case and why that accepted answer doesn't apply*

Comment: What is the benefit of writing "this is a different feature-request" where it is not different?

Comment: What answer would you like to see on that question being accepted?

Comment: I think that the feature-request is necessary. But the question owner mark the answer which tells that it is unnecessary. My question here is related to that. Not to the answer itself.

Answer (score 9):

This is a very poor [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info). You have not even explained how such a feature would benefit anyone. No justifications whatsoever...

First of all, it's always and only up to the OP which answer he decides to accept. You can't force or demand him to accepts yours or someone else's answer. It's always has been this way AFAIK and this is very reasonable. The voting system is designed to allow the community to vote on their most favorite(*to some extent - see [why voting is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and voting [down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) and [up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)*) questions and answers.

To contradict your idea I can't resist to introduce you to a [Populist Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist). It's been awared nearly 4,5K times which (*at least to me*) means that it makes sense and proves the idea that an accepted answer is not always the best answer provided.

Golden rule to remember:   **ACCEPTED ANSWER ≠ BEST ANSWER**

If you personally disagree with an accepted answer, you can either leave a comment, or downvote the answer. You can have a go an provide your own answer - however, this approach may or may not change the way OP thinks.

I honestly do not see any benefit in an additional feature which allows people another way to express their disagreement against the accepted answer. Like I've already said, it's always down to the OP which answer has *helped* him the most and no one here on SO/META can change that behaviour.

Comment: Please read my above comment I wrote when you were preparing this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think [mehow's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216899/182513) explain the general situation very well, so I'm not going to revisit anything there.  But given [your most recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216914/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-the-code-lines), I think I've finally figured out what the whole purpose of this is feature request is.

You believe that the presence of an accept answer somehow changes whether the feature would get implemented or not, so if a feature request has an accepted answer that somehow says that the feature isn't necessary then it means it won't get done.  That is absolutely not the case, especially when the individual is not speaking for Stack Exchange, Inc. (the employees usually have diamonds just like moderators, but their profile will indicate that they are employees).  In fact there is an answer from [an employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7127/182513) and he says nothing that suggests it won't get done (or will get done - so it is still up in the air).

An appropriate status tag (usually [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), but there are others) usually indicate the intentions of SE and until then the feature is still open and subject to consideration.  And even then, there have been cases where features were previously declined and have still been implemented.  If you want to attract attention to a feature because you think it would be beneficial, then you have 3 options:

- Add your own answer an explain why it would be useful
- Add a bounty to the question to attract new attention too it.
- In some very limited cases, asking a new question **might** be appropriate, however you shouldn't do it unless you are sure your question is not really a duplicate.  And just because an old feature request does not have an answer doesn't mean you should ask a new question.  On meta sites, old questions without answers can still be duplicate targets.

It is unnecessary to "downvote the acceptance" or, in most cases, to ask a new question if you just want to revisit and draw attention to an old feature question.

The reason asking a new question is usually not a good idea is you end up hurting your own cause.  There are 12,000+ open feature requests, so new questions only cause posts to get lost in the mass of feature requests.  Plus duplicates only serve to split the discussion and make it more difficult to assess community support, which will only make it harder to decide if it is worth pursuing a specific feature.

However, it is easy to understand why this might have been confusing, and also why some users try to discourage accepting answers to true feature requests unless there is some indication by the SE staff that the feature will or won't get done for that reason.

Comment: Hey @psubsee2003, thank you for trying to understand and to add some more clarification.

Comment: @Rancs To add to what psubsee2003 has said. Even if the question had no answers a feature request is still marked as duplicate if re-proposed

Comment: I think it is a different case, isn't it?

Comment: @Rancs what is a different case?

Comment: @psubsee2003 sorry, i wrote it as a response to Richard.

Comment: @Rancs My point was that you seemed to be concerned that because the question had an accepted answer you couldn't ask it again. However, actually you couldn't ask it again under *any* circumstances

Comment: @Rancs and I incorporated Richard's point into my answer as it is valid.  Asking a new question is rarely the right way to handle it.  The reason is there are 12,000+ open feature requests, so duplicates only serve to split the discussion and make it more difficult to assess community support, which will only make it harder to decide if it is worth pursuing a specific feature.

Comment: The original question is set to unaccepted state back by its owner. So at least we have an open feature-request now, altought I have no chance to give it an upvote :)