# Link to line in code snippet

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

When sharing code from Github with people, I can get a link to the exact line, which helps with clarity when I'm bringing attention to something specific. I would like to do the same when linking people to code blocks in various Stack Exchange site answers. Sometimes, there's something specific in an answer that I want to bring attention to, maybe not the answer's entire code block. Is this something on the roadmap to be supported by Stack Exchange?

Comment: As this is specifically about Stack Overflow, you should ask at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't realise that's how this works. How do I delete this?

Comment: Question posted to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393380/link-to-line-in-code-snippet)

Comment: Eh, other sites often use code blocks, and while its a feature most useful on SO, we all could use it. No real need to delete.

Comment: Well, first there should be [line numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings), then they can start planning ahead..

Comment: Assuming you need it on a different question, you could simply copy those specific lines and link to the old answer.

Comment: GitHub is a repository for code; StackExchange (and other exchanges for that matter) is a repository for knowledge.  Apples and oranges.  Code snippets should be short enough that a link to the post in question should be quick enough to identify what they are after, in my opinion.  A single line of code is easily copy / pasted for reference.

Comment: I think these are all good arguments. Thinking about it more, perhaps what I'm actually looking for is a way to bring attention to a specific item (like a line) within an answer. This is actually a problem I have with HTML and how the web works generally, a lack of consistent content-addressing especially at the atomic level.